# Queue Python threading (Segmentation fault: 11)

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a queue set up like this.  I want to run through all the items in a DB query and pass them into my Downloader class.  My DB connection keeps going away and eventually my program just dies because I think too many threads are open?

I get an error: Segmentation fault: 11

There are 100K+ items.

How can I properly fix this to process a few items at a time and speed up the process?

```
class Downloader(threading.Thread):
    """Threaded File Downloader"""

    def __init__(self, queue, db):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.db = db

    def remove_unicode(self, title):
        try:
            return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', title).encode('ascii','ignore')
        except:
            return title

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # gets the url from the queue
            row = self.queue.get()
            title = row[0]
            etc...


def main(urls):

     queue = Queue.Queue()
     # create a thread pool and give them a queue
     for i in range(5):
          t = Downloader(queue, db)
          t.setDaemon(True)
          t.start()

        # give the queue some data
     i = 1
     for url in urls:
          print i
          queue.put(url)
          i+=1
        # wait for the queue to finish
          queue.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     db = DatabaseUtil()
     sql = 'SELECT `Title`, `Site` from `XYZ`'
     titles = db.query(sql)
     main(titles)
```

Comment: Please check the indentation in the code.